# Is it possible to disable Firefox's shortcutCache? Everytime I create a shortcut it stores the .ico in the shortcutCache

Tags: firefox, icons, shortcuts

I frequently drag shortcuts from Firefox to my desktop to save them as .url files. Each .url file is just a text file that has it's icon image information:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://www.imdb.com/
IDList=
HotKey=0
IconFile=C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\su7Sedeq.default-release\shortcutCache\KoIJ7jU4RSfnuHxzNIRihQ==.ico
IconIndex=0
```

So when I re-install windows and Firefox... my profile folder is different which means all those shortcut icons that point to a different profile no longer exists and will just become blank icons.

So I was just wondering if there's a Firefox settings that prevents .url files from containing this icon information. Shortcuts created with Chrome and Edge don't save the info info:

Chrome

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://www.imdb.com/
```

Edge

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://www.imdb.com/
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to go into Firefox's `about:config` and set `browser.shell.shortcutFavicons` to `false`